# Converting samples from .get_array_of_samples() back to an AudioSegment

Tags: python, arrays, pydub

Pydub rocks! It's been very easy to do what I need however I'm running into an issue getting my data out of python...
I'm using get_array_of_samples() to extract samples from an audio file so that I can run some custom math on them.  Is it possible to convert the array of samples back to an AudioSegment?  I'm looking for ways to export my modified samples as an audio file and it seems converting back to an AudioSegment makes the most sense...

Thank you in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is :) Here's an example in [pydub's low-pass filter](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/effects.py#L245), that does just that!

The basic idea is:

```
new_audio_data = modified_array_of_samples.tostring()
new_audio_segment = original_audio_segment._spawn(data=new_audio_data)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!